# Consider only Sunday as a non-working day in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am looking for a solution for this SQL CASE below, where I want to not consider Sunday as a working day.
So if Sunday comes between a bkg_date and KPI, it is not considered.
Here's my query;

```
CASE
WHEN SYSDATE - x.bkg_date - 1 <= x.dlvry_kpi THEN CONCAT(TO_CHAR(x.dlvry_kpi - (SYSDATE - x.bkg_date), 'FM00'), ' days left')
ELSE 'OKPI'
END AS AGING
```

It doesn't include the Sunday condition, However I've tried this for Sunday but it still gives some error;

```
CASE
WHEN SYSDATE - x.bkg_date <= x.dlvry_kpi THEN 
    CONCAT(
        TO_CHAR(
            x.dlvry_kpi - (
                SYSDATE - x.bkg_date 
                + FLOOR((SYSDATE - x.bkg_date) / 7) -- Subtracting Sundays
                - CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - x.bkg_date + 1, 'DD') = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- Subtracting Sundays falling on the start date
            ),
            'FM00'
        ),
        ' days left'
    )
ELSE 'OKPI'
END AS AGING
```

Comment: Unclear... Provide sample data according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) #5 and desired output for this data according to #3.

Comment: SYSDATE = 13-Jul-2023
X.BKG_DATE = 5-Jul-2023
x.dlvry_kpi = 7 Days

Now the result should be like '00 Days left'

Comment: as soon as you need to start doing logic around working days, I'd strongly recommend considering adding a calendar table to your database. With one row per day, you're still talking less than 10000 rows for 20 years worth of data. And then you can write *arbitrary* rules for deciding which days are working days (i.e. do you not have any public holidays?)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever no, not yet

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's the thing, the data is alot I mean millions

Answer (score 0):

You can find the number of full weeks difference between the start of the weeks containing the dates and multiply the by 6 to get the number of days ignoring Sundays and then adjust for the part weeks around the start and end dates:

```sql
CASE
WHEN SYSDATE - x.bkg_date <= x.dlvry_kpi
THEN TO_CHAR(
       x.dlvry_kpi
       - ( -- Full weeks from Monday of start week to Monday of current week
           ( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( x.bkg_date, 'IW' ) ) * 6 / 7
           -- Add extra days in current week ignoring Sunday
           + LEAST( TRUNC( SYSDATE   ) - TRUNC( SYSDATE,   'IW' ) + 1, 6 )
           -- Subtract days in the week before the start date ignoring Sunday
           - LEAST( TRUNC( x.bkg_date ) - TRUNC( x.bkg_date, 'IW' ), 6 )
       ),
       'FM00'
      )
      || ' days left'
    )
ELSE 'OKPI'
END AS AGING
```

You have not included any sample data with the question so we do not know what you expected inputs or outputs are and your code appears to have some adjustment if the start date is a Sunday and it is unclear what the purpose of that is. Due to that, testing and making any adjustments for the start day being a Sunday is left as an exercise to for the OP to complete.

Comment: And if I also consider this condition that actual x.bkg_date is actually the next working day. @mt0

Comment: I tried to do 'x.bkg_date +1' everywhere